# Python Task "Even the last"

Tags: python, list, task

I have a task "You are given an array of integers. You should find the sum of the integers with even indexes (0th, 2nd, 4th...). Then multiply this summed number and the final element of the array together. Don't forget that the first element has an index of 0.

For an empty array, the result will always be 0 (zero).

Input: A list of integers.

Output: The number as an integer."

My solution is:

```
def checkio(array: list) -> int:
    """
        sums even-indexes elements and multiply at the last
    """
    summary = 0
    if len(array) > 0:
        for i in array:
            if array.index(i) % 2 == 0:
                summary += i
                print('sum = ' + str(summary) + ' index = ' + str(array.index(i)))
        res = summary * array[-1]
        return res
    else:
        return 0
```

And when it doesnt work correct, when i print indexes to see whats wrong, i got that some index is missing (in this example 16th)

```
print(checkio([-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]))
```

Output:

```
sum = -37 index = 0
sum = -56 index = 2
sum = -27 index = 4
sum = -24 index = 6
sum = -88 index = 8
sum = -52 index = 10
sum = -26 index = 12
sum = 29 index = 14
sum = -36 index = 18
-1476
```

What is the reason?

Comment: The problem is with line `if array.index(i) % 2 == 0:`. Think about it.

Comment: `-36 * 41 = -1476`  maybe

Comment: Also `array.index()` will search for first value, if you have duplicated value that won't work, look about `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `array.index()` will return the first index of the value

You have a `84` at position 9, then when you call it on the second `84`, the vall is the same `array.index(84)` so result is same : `9` and it won't count it

Use `enumarate` that make an iterator with both position and value

```py
def checkio(array: list) -> int:
    """
        sums even-indexes elements and multiply at the last
    """
    summary = 0
    if array: # true is non-empty
        for i, value in enumerate(array):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                summary += value
                print('sum =', summary,'index =', i)
        res = summary * array[-1]
        return res

    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by @azro, the problem with your code has to do with `array.index()` always returning the first index of a given element in your list, so that it will return undesired results for duplicates.

`enumerate()` is one way to go, but there's still room for some optimization here. The following bit is verbose, since it will loop over all the elements, while we already know we only need elem 0, 2, etc.

```
        for i, value in enumerate(array):
            if i % 2 == 0:
```

We could just write:

```
array = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]

def checkio1(array: list) -> int:
    """
        sums even-indexes elements and multiply at the last
    """
    summary = 0
    if array: # true is non-empty
        for i in range(0,len(array),2): # 2 is the step, so we enter elem 0, 2, etc.
            summary += array[i]
        res = summary * array[-1]
        return res

    return 0

print(checkio1(array))
1968
```

Let me share two alternative methods as well.

1. using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/):

```
import numpy as np

def checkio2(array: list) -> int:
    """
        sums even-indexes elements and multiply at the last
    """
    if not array:
        return 0
    arr = np.array(array)
    return arr[np.arange(0,len(arr),2)].sum()*arr[-1]

print(checkio2(array))
1968
print(checkio2([]))
0
```

2. using [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) from the `operator` module:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def checkio3(array: list) -> int:
    """
        sums even-indexes elements and multiply at the last
    """
    if not array:
        return 0
    return sum(itemgetter(*range(0,len(array),2))(array))*array[-1]

print(checkio3(array))
1968
print(checkio3([]))
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, use *range(start: stop: step)* to quickly select the numbers based on the even-indexes and avoid later repeatedly checking (modulus).  This is just for another reference. All previous posts work great.

I don't like to use *array* here, since it has different meaning in Python.

```
def checkio(nums: list) -> int:
    """
        sums even-indexes elements and multiply at the last
    """
    if not nums:     #  not empty
       return sum(nums[0::2]) * nums[-1]   # . just rely on range slicing here & save some modulo computations later...
    else:
       return 0
```